# Выровнять текст и SVG по горизонтальному центру

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может я чего не знаю, но каким образом можно выровнять по высоте по центру текст?

Для img используется `align="middle"`, а в этом случае как можно поступить?

Comment: display: flex; align-items: center; либо установите для этого текста line-height равный высоте блока.

Answer (score 1):

Это делается буквально в две строчки если воспользоваться [Flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox):

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.svg {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg"></div>
<p>Текст текст текст</p>
```